# how to use if and else in my django forloop

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to use an if else statement in my django template so that if the bars exist it displays them but if not then it lets me know that there are no bars available.

template.html

```
<div class="row">
    {% for bar in bars %}
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 25px!important;">
        <div class="single-promotions text-center">
            <div class="promotions-img">
                <img src="{{bar.image.url}}" class="img-fluid" style="height: 350px; width: 100%;" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="promotions-details">
                <h4>{{bar.name}}</h4>
                <h5><span>{{bar.opening_time}} -</span><span> {{bar.closing_time}}</span></h5>
                <h5>{{bar.address}}</h5>
                <a href="{% url 'reserve' bar.pk %}" class="read-more">Book a Table</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I have tried some methods but it didn't display any thing whether the bars existed or not

Comment: Try put {% if bars %} before for loop

Comment: Thanks for the answer. my mistake was that I was using {% if bar %} instead of {% if bars %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was waking a mistake of using {% if bar %} instead of {% if bars %}

template.html

```
{% if bars %}
    {% for bar in bars %}
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 25px!important;">
        <div class="single-promotions text-center">
            <div class="promotions-img">
                <img src="{{bar.image.url}}" class="img-fluid" style="height: 350px; width: 100%;" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="promotions-details">
                <h4>{{bar.name}}</h4>
                <h5><span>{{bar.opening_time}} -</span><span> {{bar.closing_time}}</span></h5>
                <h5>{{bar.address}}</h5>
                <a href="{% url 'reserve' bar.pk %}" class="read-more">Book a Table</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
<h2 style="color: white!important;">
    No bars Available, Sign Up to Create a Bar. <br> 
    <small><a style="color: white!important; text-decoration: underline;" href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up</a></small>
</h2>                
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed another easier way to solve this which is using the Django **empty** templatetag.

```
    {% for bar in bars %}
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 25px!important;">
        <div class="single-promotions text-center">
            <div class="promotions-img">
                <img src="{{bar.image.url}}" class="img-fluid" style="height: 350px; width: 100%;" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="promotions-details">
                <h4>{{bar.name}}</h4>
                <h5><span>{{bar.opening_time}} -</span><span> {{bar.closing_time}}</span></h5>
                <h5>{{bar.address}}</h5>
                <a href="{% url 'reserve' bar.pk %}" class="read-more">Book a Table</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% empty %}
      <h4>No Bars Available</h4>
    {% endfor %}
```